# beautiful soup findall not returning results

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to [webscrape](http://%20https://www.kbb.com/ford/escape/2017/s/?vehicleid=415933&intent=buy-new) and get the insurance dollars as listed in the below html.

Insurance
Insurance

Used the below code but it is not fetching anything. Can someone help? I am fairly new to python...

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.kbb.com/ford/escape/2017/s/?vehicleid=415933&intent=buy-new')

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

test2 = html_soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class":"col-base-6"})

print(test2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all the data you see on the page is actually the response to the get request to this URL. there are a lot of other requests the browser make in the background, which are initiated by javascript code.

Specifically, the request for the insurance data is made to this URL:

```
https://www.kbb.com/vehicles/hub/_costtoown/?vehicleid=415933
```

Here is a working code for what you need:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.kbb.com/vehicles/hub/_costtoown/?vehicleid=415933')

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

Insurance = html_soup.find('div',string="Insurance").find_next().text

print(Insurance)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Moshe for explaining and sharing the code as well.. I executed the code and got the desired results!